# How to add add button at bottom uiwebview in ios 7?

Tags: xcode, ios7, uiwebview, uiscrollview

how i create view like that, height web view == height off screen

```
+--------------------------+
|                          | |
|                          | |
|                          | | height of screen (960 in iphone 4s)
|         web view         | |
|                          | |
|                          | |
+--------------------------+
|                          |
| [button]        [button] |
|                          |
+--------------------------+
```

Answer (score 2):

Add UIScollView on UIView. Then add UIWebView and UIView on scrollView.
Like that:
[image]

in ViewController:

```
class ViewController: UIViewController, UIWebViewDelegate {

@IBOutlet weak var webView: UIWebView!
@IBOutlet weak var heightWebView: NSLayoutConstraint!

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    self.heightWebView.constant = self.view.bounds.height

    webView.loadRequest(NSURLRequest(URL: NSURL(string: "https://yandex.ru/")!))
    webView.scrollView.bounces = false
    webView.userInteractionEnabled = false
}

func webViewDidFinishLoad(webView: UIWebView) {
    var frame = webView.frame;
    frame.size.height = 1;
    webView.frame = frame;
    let fittingSize = webView.sizeThatFits(CGSizeZero)
    frame.size = fittingSize;
    webView.frame = frame;


    self.heightWebView.constant = fittingSize.height
}
```

}

Answer (score 0):

Create a view add webvview and toolbar.Set webview frame as 45 lesser at bottom and at the bottom add toolbar with two buttons add flexi button in between two buttons.

1.add webview 
2.add toolbar

set frame for toolbar as from bottom of self.view add the toolbar and it should fit to self.view  from bottom and add the webview frame which is 45 less than self.view

Comment: when i scroll end of web view, it don't show tool bar. can you give me example code or probject?